# Manhua/manga about a boy who could hear people's inner thoughts and had a pet/friend monkey and a talking plant that likes his blood

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manhua where this boy was basically abused by his family and he left after this party. He could hear people's inner thoughts. He has this pet/friend monkey and a talking plant that likes his blood. I’m pretty sure he turned out to be a dragon.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, which character turned out to be a dragon?

Answer (score 1):

***[Estio](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/6dd1jtu/estio)***.

> Estio is just an ordinary farmer's son but with an extraordinary ability, he can read the thoughts and memories of humans and animals. For this, he is shunned by the people in his village, finding happiness only in his animal friends. After years of silently enduring the villagers' hostility, Estio runs away the night he turns 19. His journey brings unexpected friendships and encounters, but will such bonds be able to show him there is more to him and his ability than meets the eye?

It can be read on reaper scans and has a good number of chapters.

Comment: This would be a better answer if it explained why this is the correct answer.